# How can we upsert a list of lists of accounts

Tags: apex

I want to update list of list of account. I am getting list of accounts from many sources, now i want to update them.

```
list<list<sObject>> la=new list<list<sObject>>();
la.add(accountList1);
la.add(accountList2);
upsert la;
```

Its throwing an error, is there any way through which we can upsert list of list of accounts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should instead look at the `addAll` method, which would allow you to use just one `List<Account>`:

```
List<Account> allRecords = new List<Account>();
allRecords.addAll(accountList1);
allRecords.addAll(accountList2);
upsert allRecords;
```

---

If, for some reason, you really want to maintain separate lists, you will have to flatten the structure you have in your OP:

```
List<Account> allRecords = new List<Account>();
for (List<Account> accountList : listOfLists)
    allRecords.addAll(accountList);
upsert allRecords;
```

Comment: Yes Sure @Adrian

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. You can only DML on single records or lists. Instead, make a single list and use addAll:

```
Account[] records = new Account[0];
records.addAll(accountList1);
records.addAll(accountList2);
upsert records;
```

As a side note, you also can't upsert on a generic list of SObject, so you'll need to use the Account concrete type instead.

Comment: Well, you *can* `upsert` on a generic list, you just need to be more clever about it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've never been able to accomplish this or seen it done. How do you do this?

Comment: I solved it [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64988/apex-cast-sobject-list-dynamically-to-a-specific-sobject-type/88385#88385). The only caveat is that you can't do it if you want to do `Database.upsert(List<SObject>, SObjectField, Boolean)`, because that throws a compile error instead of runtime.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You're still instantiating a concrete sobject collection, though. My point was that the original code as written would have crashed for a completely annoying reason. Still, that's a pretty nifty trick in a pinch.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by concrete? I declare and instantiate it as `List<SObject>`. Still, good idea to call it out explicitly as a stumbling block.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You're instantiating a `List<SpecificSObjectType>` by way of Type.forName, and boxing it inside a generic reference. It works because upsert tries to unbox the value to see if it's a concrete list type before throwing a runtime error. I just tried that out. The code as written by the OP used a generic list, which would compile but then fail with a runtime exception. Like I said though, it's nice to know that it's not a compile-time error, which lets us have some code reuse. In fact, I have a use for that in my current code base...