# How do I specify the sObject type when working with specific fields in a cast collection of sObjects

Tags: apex, sobject

I had to transfer a bunch of records from one user to another today. I decided to use the dev console because I needed it done quickly.

I wanted to write generic code using `sObjects` but couldn't work through it, so I ended up hard-coding the `SObjectType` and powering through it.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to write some generic code where I can specify `sObjectType`, `newOwnerId` and `currentOwnerId` and the code will update the `OwnerId` on each record from `currentOwnerId` to `newOwnerId`.

So far I've been able to query the records into a list, and cast that list to the specified sObject type ([using the approach in this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64988/apex-cast-sobject-list-dynamically-to-a-specific-sobject-type)). I'm stuck on how to work with the `OwnerId` field in the list of cast records in a for loop. Here's what I've tried:

```
string sObjType = 'Contact';
id currentOwner = '00540000001CtuIAAS'; 
id newOwner = '005400000038FL2AAM';
string listType = 'List<' + sObjType + '>';

list<sObject> sObjList = Database.query('SELECT Id,OwnerId from ' + sObjType +' Where OwnerId =: currentOwner');

list<sObject> sObjUpdate = new list<sObject>(); //will hold the records to update

list<sObject> castRecords = (List<Sobject>)Type.forName(listType).newInstance();
castRecords.addAll(sobjList);

for (sObjType s : castRecords){
    s.OwnerId = newOwner;
    SObjUpdate.add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making this implementation overly complicated. You don't need to cast the list at all.

```
public static void transfer(SObjectType sObjectType, Id formerOwnerId, Id newOwnerId)
{
    List<SObject> records = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + sObjectType + ' WHERE OwnerId = :formerOwnerId');
    for (SObject record : records) record.put('OwnerId', newOwnerId);
    try
    {
        update records;
    }
    catch (DmlException d)
    {
        // handle your DML Exceptions!
    }
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly.  i could not figure out how to construct a sObjectType record to pass into the method, so I switched it to a string --> public static void transfer(string sObjType, Id formerOwnerId, Id newOwnerId) and that worked fine