# Can I create a list of sobjects in a for loop where the name of the list will be dynamic?

Tags: apex, list, sobject, dynamic-apex

I want to create lists of sobject where sobject types will be input from a custom label or a custom metadata.

Can I create a list of sobjects in a for loop where the name of the list will be dynamic?

something like this -

```
for(Integer i=0; i<somesize; i++) {
List<SObject> listName*i* = new List<SObject>();
}
```

Comment: Your post and its title do not seem to describe very well what you want to do. You keep saying you want the name of the list to be dynamic, but it seems much more likely that you want the type of the list or the types of the records it contains are what you want to be dynamic. Could you please **[edit]** your post to make it a bit more clear? In your above post, the name of the list is `i`. Is that really what you want to be dynamic?

Comment: If the name of the list really is what you want to make dynamic, you're going to have to make clear _why_ as you are almost certainly facing an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `List<SObject>` can hold records for any type of `SObject`. So the following would work, for example:

```
List<SObject> records = new List<SObject>();
records.add(new Account());
```

So you don't need to do much to support dynamically typed lists. Unless, that is, you are trying to upsert them. Then you need to use `Type.forName` as I outlined [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/88385/2995).

```
String listType = 'List<' + sObjectType + '>';
List<SObject> castRecords = (List<SObject>)Type.forName(listType).newInstance();
```

But this type of casting should not be necessary for any other use case.

Answer (score 1):

I just responded on your previous post.

Yes, you can use the `Schema` class. `SObject` itself is dynamic.

```
List<SObject> records = new List<Sobject>();
Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
for(Integer i=0; i<somesize; i++) {
    records.add(gd.get('ObjectNameFromLabel').newSObject());
}
```

If you want to split it then you can use the instance of and use `Map<String, List<SObject>>` where key is the API name of object.

Comment: @manjit I want to create different list of sobject, where the name will be dynamic.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I actually already have the combined list of generic sobject and would like to split it, but don't know the sobjecttypes of the various records in the original list.

Comment: But _why_? Let us [further discuss in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124535/discussion-on-answer-by-manjit5190-can-i-create-a-list-of-sobjects-in-a-for-loop).